# How does Haskell infer correct type classes in MaybeT implementation?

Tags: haskell, types, monads, type-inference, monad-transformers

How does Haskell know which is correct monad instance for each `return` expression?

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }

instance Monad m => Monad (MaybeT m) where
    return  = MaybeT . return . return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually unambiguous from the context.

Let's play the typechecker,

```
-- From the signature
MaybeT . return . return :: a -> MaybeT a 
-- From the type of MaybeT
return . return :: a -> m (Maybe a)
-- From the type of `.`
(return :: Maybe a -> m a) . (return :: a -> Maybe a)
```

And once we have the type of each `return`, the "instance selection algorithm" will correctly choose the first to use `m`s `return` and the second to be `Maybe`.

Comment: Shouldn't the first return on the last line be either of type `Maybe a -> m (Maybe a)` or the more general `b -> m b` with `b ~ Maybe a`?

Comment: @Laar Technically yes, but it's easier (and morally equivalent) to treat it this way.

Answer (score 4):

It infers the needed types.

It's clear from the meaning of an `instance` definition that we're trying to define

```
returnMaybeT :: Monad m => a -> MaybeT m a
returnMaybeT x = MaybeT (return (return x))
```

Since `MaybeT :: m (Maybe a) -> MaybeT a` (taken as a function) we know that the inner stack of `return`s must have type

```
return (return x) :: Monad m => a -> m (Maybe a)
```

Now, we know that `return` is a polymorphic function which has a type like

```
return :: a -> n a
```

for *any* `Monad` `n`. In the case of this first `return`, the `Monad m =>` constraint tells us that `m` is a `Monad` and so we can use its definition of return. This lets us get all the way down to the inner `return`

```
return x :: a -> Maybe a
```

and since we know that `Maybe` has a `Monad` instance we can use the `return` from that.

---

Ultimately, all the compiler has to do is whittle its way down the expression trying to determine the types needed at each `return`. After it determines the needed type it has to check to see if it knows a `Monad` instance for that type. This is simple for `Maybe`, since it's concrete, but a little more difficult to see for `m` since it's just a variable.

The reason `m` works is because we've constrained the variable to certainly be *some* type which instantiates `Monad`.